# Status code 302 does not redirect after a POST call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, redirect, http-redirect

After submitting a form (POST) I successfully get a 302 redirect, as expected, but the browser does not follow it:

[image: response from form]

I do get a 200 status code with the full "redirected" html code but the browser does not render it or redirect to the url.

[image: response from redirection]

The 302 status code is generated by a rails app (Devise::PasswordsController#update) with the line:

```
redirect_with resource, location: "/"
```

What is going on? How can I tell the browser to follow the redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 302 request was intercepted by a javascript/jQuery script that did not allow the browser redirect using `e.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had used `bootstrap_form` Then I added `local: true` and it resovled, Otherwise it will be sent with ajax request